# How to convert List<Class> to Dictionary<string, List<String>> in C#?

Tags: c#, string, windows, list, dictionary

[image]I have `Class` with properties of `String` and `List<String>`. I want to convert this `List<Class>` to a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>`, but I could not do this. How to convert `List<Class>` directly to a `Dictionary?`

```
public class SerializationClass
{
    string key;
    List<string> values;

    public SerializationClass()
    {

    }
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.key;
        }
        set
        {
            this.key = value;
        }
    }

    public List<string> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return this.values;
        }
        set
        {
            this.values = value;
        }
    }

    public SerializationClass(string _key, List<string> _values)
    {
        this.Key = _key;
        this.Values = _values;
    }
}
```

And the population of List is,

```
List<SerializationClass> tempCollection = new List<SerializationClass>();
```

Here I want to convert to convert the `tempCollection` to `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(tempCollection.Count);
```

tempCollection has to be converted to tempDict?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks and Regards,

Amal Raj.

Comment: What you tried anything?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply Call Linq's `ToDictionary` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, only condition is `key` for each element needs to be unique, or else it will fail since `Dictionary` wants a unique key

```
var tempDict = tempCollection.ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.values);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do i have to add any dll reference. Because i have already tried ToDictionary(), but i could not use it.

Comment: Use System.Linq, dll and namespace

Comment: @Amal can't see any error pop up, where have you pasted

Comment: Check the following link, you can also get the Nuget reference:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq/

Comment: There's ambiguity between which method to call, as two binaries imported in your solution have same method implemented, looks like you have imported two different linq related binaries, check. One is mostly wrapper which you don't need